# TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes() replaces the current attribute insead of adding it

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, typedescriptor

I have this portion of code:

```
var hasAttribute = TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(property.DeclaringType).OfType<CrmTypeAttribute>()
            .Any((attr)
                    => ((CrmTypeAttribute)attr).Name == property.Name);

            if (!hasAttribute)
            {
                var crmTypeAttribute = new CrmTypeAttribute(property.Name, crmType);
                TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(property.DeclaringType, crmTypeAttribute);
            }
```

It has two problems:

1. For some reason OfType returns an empty IEnumerable although it should return the right attributes of that type, and I checked. They exist.
2. This is the severe problem. Instead of adding the attribute it replaces the old attribute of the same type with crmTypeAttribute. **I have marked AllowMultiple to be true.**

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code?
EDIT:
For some reason it allows adding only one attribute of an attribute type, I have added another attribute type at runtime and it worked.

Comment: You sure about that? :) I'm not 100% sure that you're using the TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes call correctly, though I'm also not 100% sure that you're using it wrong either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the attribute needs to override the TypeId property of the Attribute class to not be treated as duplicated.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w3a7b50.aspx) for details, it's very hidden and should be mentioned in GetAttributes as well.

Comment: Thank you for the research! I had the same problem and your solution helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem stems from the fact that you're ignoring the returned `TypeDescriptionProvider` from the `AddAttributes` call.

From Reflector on `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes`:

> Adds class-level attributes to the
>   target component type.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **type**: The `Type` of the target component.
>
> **attributes**: An array of `Attribute` objects to add to the component's class.
>
> **Return Value**: The newly created `TypeDescriptionProvider` that was used to add the specified attributes.

There is always a new `TypeDescriptionProvider` instance created when calling that static method. You should rely on this newly-created provider instance when adding further attributes and also querying for recently-added attributes.