# How does Xaml create the string to BitmapImage value conversion when binding to Image.Source?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, dependency-properties

I'm creating an `Image.Source`-`String` binding in code like:

```
var newBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding()
  {
    Path = new PropertyPath("MyImageUrl")
  };
BindingOperations.SetBinding(attachedObject, Image.SourceProperty, newBinding);
```

This approach works well for, for example, `TextBlock.TextProperty`-`String` bindings, but for the `Image.Source`-`String` I ideally would like the `Binding` to automatically insert a conversion for me - in the same way that the Xaml binding does when I use:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" />
```

I realise I can add my own converter to mimic the Xaml binding behaviour, but I'd like to see if there's some way to do exactly what the Xaml does.

Is there some way to get the new `Binding` to automatically add it's own string->BitmapImage `ValueConverter` during the code-based bind evaluation?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly. What is the type of the property (MyImageUrl) you would like to bind? Because the code you gave is equivalent to doing <Image Source="{Binding MyImageUrl"}/> in Xaml. The property can be a string, Uri or ImageSource and should work in all cases.

Comment: No - if I create that exact binding in code then it fails to work for a string.

Comment: hmmm. I just tried, working fine. Are you getting any exceptions or the image just doesn't show?

Comment: Interesting - not working for me on wp7 emulator or wp8 phone. What did you try in? Wp7? wp8? Other?

Comment: I tried on wp8. This may sound silly, but can you double check that your property returns a correct image path string?

Comment: It returns an http:// URL to placekitten.com :) I am working in a wp7 based lib though. It's getting late here... Will try afresh tomorrow...

Comment: Just tried on WP7 and it actually did not work there but works on WP8

Comment: @AlaaMasoud OK - I'm seeing the results consistently now in any code built for wp7 (even if it's run on wp8) - so I guess this is a little something that was broken in wp7. Will open a new question to see if anyone knows the difference and an easy way around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System.Windows.Media.ImageSource has a `TypeConverterAttribute`

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ImageSourceConverter))]
```

The binding will look for this and use the converter automatically.

If you look at the `ImageSourceConverter` you can see what types it can convert from:

```
if (sourceType == typeof(string) || 
    sourceType == typeof(Stream) || 
    sourceType == typeof(Uri) || 
    sourceType == typeof(byte[]))
{
    return true;
}
```

In order to mimic this process, you must add a `TypeConverterAttribute` on the Type of the property being bound to.

You can do this by 1. controlling the type, or 2. use the `TypeDescriptor` at runtime to add the attribute.  There's a question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997471/typedescriptor-addattributes-replaces-the-current-attribute-insead-of-adding-i).

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem I've got is that something behaved differently on Wp7... On Wp8, this seems to work perfectly.