# How to does WindowsRT Data-binding do type conversion without TypeConverterAttribute

Tags: data-binding, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, typeconverter

In a previous question/answer I learnt how data-binding in Windows Phone does TypeConversion for `string` to `ImageSource` using the `TypeConverterAttribute` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16753488/373321

I'm now looking at the same problem in WindowsStore apps where `TypeConverterAttribute` [doesn't exist](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/metro/csharpvb.aspx?ID=f8a0af25-7141-4339-8889-b791166f450e).

If I use WinRT data-binding then clearly the data-binding layer still manages to do the correct conversion. The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source) says:

> this behavior relies on underlying type conversion that processes the string as a URI, and calls the equivalent of the BitmapImage(Uri) constructor.

However, I can't see any meta-data anywhere about how it knows what conversion to do.

I'm trying to build my own data-binding implementation - so being able to mimic what WinRT does would be very useful.

Is there a queryable metadata hint somewhere which tells the Xaml data-binding what conversion to apply? Or is this `string` to `ImageSource` conversion somehow baked into the run-time, hidden from the CLR layer?

If it is hidden, is there a list anywhere of known automatic type conversions so that I could cache them in my data-binding implementation?

Answer (score 2):

I discussed this question via Twitter with one of the WinRT devs (Tim Heuer)

A basic summary of this conversation was:

- WinRT does not have anything like `TypeConverterAttribute`
- A small number of WinRT controls do have a small number of internal conversions that they will apply
- There is no information publicly available about which controls and conversions these are

Comment: Ah, that's a bit disappointing to hear. I was working on a usercontrol, and the lack of this crippled its use in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8 Apps, this is generally handled by creating a class that inherits from `IValueConverter`, and is then assigned alongside the particular data binding. As stated on the msdn site:
"Create a converter by implementing the `IValueConverter` interface and implementing the Convert method. That method should return an object that is of **the same type** as the dependency property that the binding targets, or at least a type that can be implicitly coerced or converted to the target type."

Here is the link to the full doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.converter.aspx

See the "Examples" section for further detail.

To answer your question, there is no metadata hint, you simply create your converter and then explicitly assign the converter alongside your custom data binding.