# WPF Dependency Property Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm looking at a WPF control (NotifyIconWpf https://bitbucket.org/hardcodet/notifyicon-wpf/src ) and I don't quite get how the binding on dependency property works.

The control has a dependency property called `TaskbarIcon.IconSource` which is used to set the icon for the system tray icon, from the code I can see `IconSource` is of type `ImageSource`.

However in XAML it can be set to a string like `IconSource="/Red.ico"`, or I can bind it to `IconSource="{Binding MyIcon}"` where `MyIcon` is a string in the DataContext.

How does this string gets magically converted to `ImageSource`.. am I missing anything obvious here?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion is done by the [`ImageSourceConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesourceconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) class, which is able to convert from `string`, `Uri` and `byte[]` to `ImageSource`.

It is registered as TypeConverter for the `ImageSource` class like this:

```
[TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ImageSourceConverter))]
public abstract class ImageSource : Animatable, IFormattable
```

Read more about type conversion here: [TypeConverters and XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970913(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Similar question answered in this SO Post: [How does Xaml create the string to BitmapImage value conversion when binding to Image.Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752242/how-does-xaml-create-the-string-to-bitmapimage-value-conversion-when-binding-to)  which explains the process.  Basically, System.Windows.Media.ImageSource has a TypeConverterAttribute that performs the conversion automatically.